# Mockito Distinguish Ambiguous any() Collection vs List

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock an overloaded method that takes the following arguments:

`Collection<Foo>`

`List<Pair<Foo, Bar>>`

My problem is I want to do `Mockito.when` to get the list-based method. But if I do `Mockito.anyList` then that's still ambiguous because that's still a collection.

I have tried doing `Mockito.any(List.class)` but that's also ambiguous, and when I try `Mockito.any(List<Pair>.class)` I can't get it from the parameterized type.

What can I do to distinguish them? `Mockito.listOf` seemed promising but hasn't worked thus far.

Comment: can you paste complete method signature which u want to mock? is type casting inside any() does help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this: `ArgumentMatchers.<List<Pair<Foo, Bar>>>any()`

Comment: Thanks - a variant of this worked great for me:

ArgumentMatchers.<Pair<Foo, Bar>>anyList()

Answer (score 0):

You can hold your argument matcher in a variable with expected type, and thus resolve the ambiguity.

```
List<Pair<Foo, Bar>> listMatcher = ArgumentMatchers.anyList();
Mockito.when(myVar.doSth(listMatcher)).thenReturn(someValue);
```